# Не корректное отображение текста

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Текст выводится с помощью JS скрипта из файла. При выводе русских символов выводится непонятные символы. Как исправить?

```
setInterval(function() {
  $.get("text.txt", function(data) { 
    $("#content").text(data); 
  });
}, 5000);
```

Выводит:

> Р°С‹РІС‹Р°

Comment: В хеде какая кодировка стоит? <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> есть?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> присутствует

Comment: charset=UTF-8 заменить на charset=windows-1251

Comment: замена не помогает

Comment: Приведите фрагмент кода. А также прикрепите результат, который получается и ожидаемый. Так будет намного проще помочь в решении вашего вопроса

Comment: Наверно, у вас на сервере не выставлена кодировка по умолчанию, которая должна быть utf-8